# Excluding school-areas using Overpass-Turbo

Tags: overpass-api

As an example see: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/PV6

How do I exclude the gyms on school-property?

I tried `-relation["amenity"="school"]` but I get

```
parse error: Unknown type "-"
static error: For the attribute "type" of the element "query" the only allowed values are "node", "way", "relation" or "area".
parse error: ';' expected - 'relation' found.
```

Comment: Do you mind if you add your script. Because the script in the link is an example, not source of the error. As understood from the error, you miss semicolon before `-relation["amenity"="school"]`.

Comment: sorry for the missing error containing code, this can be found here: https://pastebin.com/h3xGAkky

the example might be used to have a place to test and im sorry to tell, that I didn't forget the `;`

Comment: There is no `gym` text as a key or a value in result. Do you want to exclude all schools from result? If so try `relation["amenity"!="school"]`